# Passing parameter from template to view (link)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to call a view from a template and pass parameters to the view (see below). However, the code throws the following error:

```
Reverse for 'project_list' with arguments '(u'member',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

**from the template:**

```
<a class="btn" href="{% url project_list 'member' %}">Member</a>
```

**from the view:**

```
def project_list(request, projects_to_show = 'All'):
    if projects_to_show == 'member':
    ...
```

**from urls.py:**

```
url(r'^projects/$', 'project_app.views.project_list', name="project_list"),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your urls.py

Comment: Is it enough with the line above from urls.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `project_list` URL doesn't take any parameters. You'll need to define another URL which does take a `projects_to_show` parameter:

```
url(r'^projects/(?P<projects_to_show>\w+)$', 'project_app.views.project_list', name="project_list_filtered"),
```

and then:

```
<a class="btn" href="{% url project_list_filtered 'member' %}">Member</a>
```

Comment: Okey. But does that mean I can't access the projects page with '/projects', but need to add another step, e.g. '/projects/member'?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that, that's why this is an extra URL rather than replacing the existing one.

Comment: On second glance, that is true, since there's a default value for the parameter. My fault.

Comment: This worked if I changed to ... project_app.views.project_list_filtered'... and renamed the view to that (of course kept the project_list, as a separate view). Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a separate view, that was my whole point. Two URLs can point to the same view.

Answer (score 1):

Both your URL and view need to accept your argument.

URL:

```
url(r'^projects/(?P<member>[\w]+)$', 'project_app.views.project_list', name="project_list"),
```

View:

```
def project_list(request, projects_to_show = 'All'):
    if projects_to_show == 'member':
    ...
```

You can read the docs about reverse URL resolution [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

Comment: I ask you the same as I asked the other answerer: Does that mean I can't access the projects page with '/projects', but need to add another step, e.g. '/projects/member'?

Comment: You mean pass it _to_ the view (from the template)?